# Momentum operator in Geometric Quantization vs momentum operator on arbitrary curved space(time)s

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, quantization

In the following stack exchange post [Momentum Operator in curved spacetime (QFT)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/470379/momentum-operator-in-curved-spacetime-qft/496627#496627) a general expression for the momentum operator is given for a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. Similarly, [Frederic Schuller's lectures explained the geometric aspects of this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C93KzJ7-Es4). To make sense out of this, we should think of the wave function as a section of a complex line bundle, which is associated to the frame bundle $LM$ of the manifold $(M,g)$. In this case, the momentum operator will be a covariant derivative, with Christoffel symbols given in the Stack Exchange post, or in the video I linked.

At the same time, we can think of a classical system not only in the Lagrangian point of view, where the Riemannian metric plays a crucial role on the tangent bundle, but we can view a classical system as a symplectic manifold with a given distinguished observable $H$, namely a triple $(M,\omega,H)$. This is the starting point of the programme of Geometric Quantization. There we will construct similarly a prequantum line bundle over the symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, whose curvature 2-form(which is determined by the connection) has to be equal to the symplectic form. Of course, there are further details as of choosing a polarization etc. But at this point, we can already define the momentum operator using the Souriau-Kostant definition: $P(p):=-ih \nabla_{X_p}+p$.

Now my question is: how can one relate the above two? Namely, how can one see that the Christoffel symbols defined in the first approach determine the connection in the second case, where the connection is determined by the symplectic form? Or how are the two operators: the Kostant-Souriau prequantum operator and the one in the first approach (general coordinates) related? I thought prequantization already works in a coordinate-independent manner.

Update: A probably better formulation of the question: how is the line bundle associated to the frame bundle in the first approach related to the prequantum bundle from Geometric Quantization? I do not see how the connections on them are related.

Comment: Perhaps take a step back and ask the following question: How is the metric $g$ reflected on $(M,\omega)$ at all? It's not obvious to me that you should expect to be able to take the standard procedure of geometric quantization and expect it to do something meaningful when the underlying $M$ has a non-trivial $g$.

Comment: Yes, this is a completely fair point. However, I found in some resources e.g. Simms, Snyaticki,Woodhouse, that indeed one can use Geometric Quantization for geodesic flows, i.e. quantize a hamiltonian H:=g^ab p_a p_b. The problem is, I do not really understand what they are doing/ how is it related to what I know about Geometric Quantization. An other reason why Geometric Quantization *should* work even if there is an underlying non-trivial g is, because we can use Geometric Quantization to quantize Kahler manifolds.