# Momentum Operator in Anti de Sitter spacetime

Tags: momentum, dirac-equation, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Im studying the dirac equation in two dimensional anti de sitter space with metric
\begin{align*}
g_{\mu\nu}= -\frac{L^2}{\cos^2(\theta)}\left( \begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/470379/momentum-operator-in-curved-spacetime-qft) (and other) article, the momentum operator in curved spacetime is given by
\begin{align}
\hat{p}_a=-i\hbar(\partial_a+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial_a\sqrt{g}}{\sqrt{g}})
\end{align}
So in $AdS_2$ it should look like $\hat{p}=-i\hbar(\partial_\theta+\tan{\theta})$

The Dirac-Hamiltonian in $AdS_2$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\hat{H}_{AdS} = \left( \begin{array}{rr}
-i\hbar c(\partial_\theta+\frac{\tan{\theta}}{2}) & -\frac{Lmc^2}{\cos{\theta}} \\ 
-\frac{Lmc^2}{\cos{\theta}} & i\hbar c(\partial_\theta+\frac{\tan{\theta}}{2})
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}

Usualy one would assume, that the diagonal elements of this Hamiltonian are equal to $\pm c\hat{p}$. I hope I didnt do any mistakes on the calculations, but in the Hamiltonian there is a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the tangent. I checked the calculations multiple times and I cant find my mistake here. So must there be a mistake in my calculations here, or are there other reasons why the diagonal elements of the Hamitonian are not equal to $c\hat{p}$ as expected?

Edit: What also confuses me is the fact, that the Hamiltonian is not hermitian because of the tangent terms. I also dont know how to make sense of it.

Comment: Are you including the spin connection terms? They are needed when taking covariant derivatives of spinors. Your $p$ operator looks as if it is set up  to act only on scalar fields.

Comment: Yes I did. I used the covariant derivative for spinors $\nabla_\nu = \partial_\nu+\frac{1}{8}\omega_{ab\nu}[\gamma^a,\gamma^b]$ where $\gamma^a, \gamma^b$ are the flat gamma matrices. Then the dirac equation is $[i\gamma^\mu\nabla_\mu-m]\Psi=0$, with the curved gamma matrices $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2g^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Then your Dirac  looks right. I have never computed the $\omega$'s for AdS.  I probably should do as Ihave been  playing with the Laplace eigenmodes for Euclidedan 2-d AdS (i.e. Lobachevski space) following the lovely book by Audrey Terras.